# Add Entitity Framework model for WPF .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on a project that uses .NET Core 7.0 and I would like to create the Entity Framework models for the database.

I used to do this with EF6 and .Net Framework 4.8 adding an ADO template and setting connection string into the app.config file.
Now, with NET Core, ADO is not supported and I am finding different methods to add the models instead.

Is there any GUI template to do it for .NET Core? What is the proper way to do it?

This method is working for me: using the nuget console, model files are created

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=XPS15\SQLEXPRESS;Database=FBase;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustedServerCertificate=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir "EFData"
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand what "ADO" (and "ADO.NET") refer to...  Anyway, I suggest you google for "appsettings.json" as that's what we're using now instead of `app.config`.

Comment: Everything about EF Core scaffolding can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli Unfortunately the old EDMX designer view that was available in EF Framework is no longer supported. Personally I've always used a more manual approach to DB-First configuration. More control, less generated smudges in the code-base, and fewer surprises.